# Eclipse IDE 3.6.2: restart and Tomcat no longer serves project..?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, spring-mvc, restart

I don't know what else will help diagnose this problem:

- running on Windows 7, 64-bit (6GB RAM, Q720 laptop)
- JDK 1.6, SpringMVC, ...
- everything was running and working Monday (and the months before that)
- came back today (Wed) and shut down Eclipse IDE to free up the RAM briefly
- started Eclipse, waiting until the CPU cycles went down and started Tomcat 7.0 from my Servers tab

Result: Tomcat starts in 1.9 seconds instead of ~20 seconds, skipping what looks like any application loading.  No errors, no warnings more than usual.  I tried refreshing the browser tab for one public page and got a 404.

I've tried doing a clean build of the project, clean and full publish of the project to the server, and remove and re-add the project to Tomcat (all within Eclipse) with the same results.

Then I tried going to the project root in the browser and I get an error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp (line: 3, column: 0) The absolute uri: http://www.springframework.org/tags cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

Almost all our JSPs include:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring"  uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form"        uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

But suddenly the springframework.org -> springsource.org turns up 404s for tags and form.  But that couldn't be why Tomcat doesn't seem to try starting my project anymore... is it?

The application's log file in Tomcat is never written to after this Eclipse restart.

The only thing to change in the project was that I loaded a new version of on JAR after restarting Eclipse, but if there was a problem because of that the logs would have thrown related errors, right?

Thanks for any diagnostic or ideas for fixing this!

Comment: Solution: Servers (tab) > right-click on Tomcat, 1) "Clean Tomcat Work Directory...", 2) "Clean..." (difference?), 3) "Publish".